# Alphabetical counter

Tags: php, counter, alphabetical

Hello PHP professionals,

With:

`$count = 0; // start count`

`$count = $count +1; // addition value`

i can define an automatic counter per text paragraph.
At each paragraph the value will be incremented automatically:

1st paragraph: `echo $count++;`. (results is 1.) text

2nd paragraph: `echo $count++;`. (results is 2.) text

3rd paragraph: `echo $count++;`. (results is 3.) text

4th paragraph: `echo $count++;`. (results is 4.) text

etc.
this works without errors.

Question:

How could it be achieved that not digits 1 to x are output, but alphabetically from A to Z?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

$letter = chr($count + 65);

If you have more than 26 paragraphs use modulo

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting with `0`, you can start with `'A'` or `"A"`. The [increment operator in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) works for letters as well:

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

In your case you simply write `$count = 'A';` and use `echo $count++;` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

The `chr()` function transfers the passed in integer into the according ACSII character.

So you can do this:

```php
$count = 1;

echo chr(65 + $count++); // 'A' == 65
echo chr(65 + $count++);
echo chr(65 + $count++);
```

Answer (score 0):

It work fine, and for small letters it works with:

```
echo chr(97 + $count++); // 'a' == 97
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry, this must be at the and of the theme.